# RTK Query: How to make the spinner component work until a response is received from both requests: mutation and refetch by tag

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I have recently started to learn RTK Query, and encountered a problem, in my application, if you click add album - it will run mutation by `function addAlbum()`
Button:

```
<button onClick={handleCreateAlbum} className="border-slate-700 border-2 px-4 py-1 mb-3 transition hover:bg-green-400 rounded-lg">Add album</button>
```

Function:

```
const handleCreateAlbum = () => {
      createAlbum(user)
    }
```

but within the function handleCreateAlbum I can only interact with this mutation, which does not allow me to wait for refetch request which is called by the tag

```
createAlbum: builder.mutation<IAlbum, IUser>({
        invalidatesTags : (result, error, user) => {
          return [{type : 'Album', id : user.id}]
        },
        query: (user) => {
          return {
            url : '/albums',
            method: 'POST',
            body : {
              userId: user.id,
              name: faker.commerce.productName()
            }
          }
        }
      }),
fetchAlbums : builder.query<IAlbum[], IUser>({
        providesTags : (result, error, user) => {
          return [{type : 'Album', id : user.id}]
        },
        query: (user) => {
          return {
            url: 'albums',
            method : 'GET',
            params : {
              userId : user.id
            },
          }
        }
      })
```

Because of this, I get what I think is a crusty logical expression to make my spinner component work when BOTH queries work:

```
const {data, error, isLoading, isSuccess, isFetching, status} = useFetchAlbumsQuery(user);
const [createAlbum, { isLoading : albumIsLoading, isSuccess : albumIsSuccess }] = useCreateAlbumMutation(); 
{(!isLoading && isFetching) || albumIsLoading && <Spinner />}
```

Can you please tell me how to make the code better or what is the way to track other requests dependent on the tag from mutation, so that the spinner spins until both requests are worked out?

I tried adding a logical expression
`{(!isLoading && isFetching) || albumIsLoading && <Spinner />}`
But I would like to know a way to track the end of dependent queries in a different way

Comment: Having a logical expression like that is pretty much the way to do it.